# Simple Collision Detection in Javascript / Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, collision-detection

I am working on a portion of a project that I am trying to detect when certain divs hit each other. In the code that I made, that doesn't work, I basically say take the first div's left amount, compare it to the other div's left amount, if they are within a certain amount it triggers an alert. If I get that much to work I am going to implant a way to say that if the distance between the two divs is 0 then it will run a certain function. I am afraid the scope of this project is too big for me, even though I am basically at the last part, because I have spent hours researching a simple way to add collision detection, but everything I find looks like rocket science to me, that is why I tried to create my own way below. **So in summary, what I want to know is why my collision detection code doesn't work, how I can make it work if possible, and if not possible what is the next best option that I should use.**

---

```
  //Collision
  function collision(){
    var tri = $('#triangle');
    var enemyPos = $('.object1').css('left');
    var minHit = enemyPos - 32.5;
    var maxHit = enemyPos + 32.5;
    var triLoc = tri.css('left');
    if(triLoc > minHit && triLoc < maxHit){
      alert('hit');
    }
  }
  collision();
}
}
```

full code: https://jsfiddle.net/kc59vzpy/

Comment: There are other issues in your fiddle. Is that the code from your project? In line 2 you reference `#bllt` but in your code you use `bllt` as a class. Regardless, when the code initializes, `blltCord` can't be anything as the element doesn't exist yet. Later you try to access the `top` of it, which causes an error. Run your fiddle while watching the console in your browser's dev tools to see it.

Comment: Not sure if what you trying to track is the bullet itself or your triangle/ship because you are checking for collision only when firing a bullet. You code seems to indicate ship collision though. You might have to check against not just X but Y coordinates as well. You also need to use position values instead of css values.

Comment: Had some time to kill so I rewrote it from scratch: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2ws46xqa/ (no bullets yet)

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have above is definitely where the problem is, then you need to look at the `enemyPos` variable. Getting the left position also adds `px`, so `enemyPos` is `100px` or something like that. When you add 32.5, you get `100px32.5` and when you subtract you get `NaN`, neither of which you want.

Before you add or subtract, use `enemyPos = parseInt($('.object1').css('left'));` to turn it into an actual number.

Comment: should probably use parseFloat in this instance for precision, in case the css value is a floating point number